# PHPUnit HTML and Clover coverage reports differ due to codeCoverageIgnore

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, clover

I'm using PHPUnit 3.5.14 and have a suite of tests which covers 100% of my PHP application excluding certain portions with // @codeCoverageIgnore[Start|End].  The HTML coverage report shows 100% coverage.  But when I generate a Clover XML coverage report, which I'd like Jenkins to read to enforce the 100% coverage requirement, it shows all of my ignored code as not covered.

For example, I have a controller class with 20 methods, one of which looks like this:

```
// @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
/**
 * Gets an instance of Foo.  Abstracted for testing.
 *
 * @param array $options The constructor argument
 *
 * @return Foo
 */
protected function _getFoo(array $options)
{
    return new Foo($options);
}
// @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

The HTML coverage report shows 20 methods covered including the one entirely ignored:

pic: coverage report excerpt

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvpN5.png

But the Clover XML report shows 19/20 methods covered and doesn't mention _getFoo:

```
<class name="CampaignController" namespace="global" (...)>
  <metrics methods="20" coveredmethods="19" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="532" coveredstatements="532" elements="552" coveredelements="551"/>
```

...

```
  <line num="592" type="stmt" count="1"/>
  <line num="593" type="stmt" count="1"/>
  <line num="615" type="method" name="createAction" crap="2" count="2"/>
  <line num="617" type="stmt" count="2"/>
```

(The _getFoo lines at the top are lines 596-608.)

The logging section of my PHPUnit configuration looks like this:

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="../public/build/coverage" charset="UTF-8"
        yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="90" highLowerBound="100"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="../public/build/test-coverage.xml"/>
</logging>
```

**Is there a way to configure the Clover coverage log entry, or change my coverage ignore comments, so that the Clover report indicates 100% coverage to match the HTML report?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in `PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover::process()`. While it correctly ignores marked lines while adding up the number of lines in a method, it gets the list of methods from `PHP_Token_Stream` which doesn't know about those code coverage comments. I created [issue #54](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/54) at github which should be relatively easy to fix.

BTW, reading `PHP_CodeCoverage::getLinesToBeIgnored()` which `PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover` uses, it appears that you can ignore an entire class or method by adding `@codeCoverageIgnore` to its docblock.

```
/**
 * Gets an instance of Foo.  Abstracted for testing.
 *
 * @param array $options The constructor argument
 * @return Foo
 *
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
```

While this won't solve the problem, it is easier than using matching `//` comments.

**Update:** If you want to try out a fix, replace the `foreach` loop over the methods inside `PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover::process()` with this modified version.

```
foreach ($_class['methods'] as $methodName => $method) {
    $methodCount        = 0;
    $methodLines        = 0;
    $methodLinesCovered = 0;

    for ($i  = $method['startLine'];
         $i <= $method['endLine'];
         $i++) {
        if (isset($ignoredLines[$i])) {
            continue;
        }

        $add   = TRUE;
        $count = 0;

        if (isset($files[$filename][$i])) {
            if ($files[$filename][$i] != -2) {
                $classStatistics['statements']++;
                $methodLines++;
            }

            if (is_array($files[$filename][$i])) {
                $classStatistics['coveredStatements']++;
                $methodLinesCovered++;
                $count = count($files[$filename][$i]);
            }

            else if ($files[$filename][$i] == -2) {
                $add = FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            $add = FALSE;
        }

        $methodCount = max($methodCount, $count);

        if ($add) {
            $lines[$i] = array(
              'count' => $count,
              'type'  => 'stmt'
            );
        }
    }

    if ($methodLines > 0) {
        $classStatistics['methods']++;

        if ($methodCount > 0) {
            $classStatistics['coveredMethods']++;
        }

        $lines[$method['startLine']] = array(
          'count' => $methodCount,
          'crap'  => PHP_CodeCoverage_Util::crap(
                       $method['ccn'],
                       PHP_CodeCoverage_Util::percent(
                         $methodLinesCovered,
                         $methodLines
                       )
                     ),
          'type'  => 'method',
          'name'  => $methodName
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your change fixes my problem inasmuch as it gives me a report which indicates 100% coverage and should allow me to automate that requirement.  Thanks, and thanks for the docblock tip.

But your change gives me this:  `<metrics methods="19" coveredmethods="19" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="532" coveredstatements="532" elements="551" coveredelements="551"/>`  So it's treating the ignored code as nonexistent while the HTML report treats it as covered.  Arguably makes more sense but the two should probably be consistent.

Comment: I guess I never paid close enough attention. I would prefer the HTML report to treat ignored lines as dead code, just like comments. Ignoring code means "I cannot test this" rather than "I have proven this code correct."

Comment: I agree.  Not sure how Sebastian feels on the matter - I can't imagine this question has never come up in the past.